# Erro "'unistd.h': No such file or directory" com flex

Tags: visual-studio, flex

Depois de criar o ficheiro `.l`, colocar os comando necessários do flex na linha de comandos do *Visual Studio* dá sempre este erro. Já tentei colocar a biblioteca mencionada no diretório mas o problema mantém-se.

Erro:

> ```
> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Versão 19.11.25547 para x86
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.
>
> lex.yy.c
> lex.yy.c(397): warning C4005: 'yywrap': redefinição de macro
> lex.yy.c(73): note: consulte a definição anterior de 'yywrap'
> calcula.l(5): fatal error C1083: Não é possível abrir arquivo incluir: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory
> ```

Código do ficheiro `.l`:

> ```
> %option main
> %x COMENT
> %%
> "//"              BEGIN( COMENT );
> .|\n|\r
> <COMENT>.         ECHO;
> <COMENT>\n|\r     BEGIN( INITIAL ); 
> %%
> ```

Comment: Você pôs o texto inteiro a ser link da imagem de propósito?

Comment: Não foi propositado. Sou nova aqui.

Comment: Peço desculpa, já alterei

Comment: Não, o projeto é cedido pelo professor. Um exemplo simples de um compilador que deve aceitar comentários em C++.

Comment: Acho que entendi o flex agora, mas é estranho isto usar unistd.h, tente usar o parametro `--wincompat` ou então talvez terá que instalar o cygwin ou gnuwin32

Comment: Não sei se não me soube explicar. Vou tornar a fazê-lo: O objetivo é criar um ficheiro (tipo txt) no formato `.l` e fazer com que este trabalhe como um compilador. Através do desenvolverdor do visual studio ao chamar a ferramenta flex com o comando `win_flex aaa.l`,por exemplo seguindo o comando `cl lex.yy.c` e mandando executar o `lex.yy`. E, neste momento, no desenvolvedor, só deve reproduzir algo em forma de comentário. No meu caso, consigo colocar o comando `cl lex.yy.c`, ele cria o lex.yy.obj mas depois ao colocar `lex.yy` dá o erro mencionado

Comment: no `win_flex` adiciona o parametro `--wincompat` como eu disse no comentario anterior, assim por exemplo `win_flex --wincompat aaa.l`

Comment: Já funciona com esse parâmetro. Obrigada pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `unistd.h` não existe no VS, geralmente é necessário adicionar algo como cygwin ou GnuWin32, mas o caso não é bem o VS e sim o `win_flex` que esta gerando os arquivos, portanto adicionar algo como cygwin ou GnuWin32 é desnecessário.

Para que o flex não adicione dependências não suportadas pelo Windows, ou melhor para que a aplicação flex fique compatível com o Windows use o parâmetro `--wincompat`, assim:

```
win_flex --wincompat foo.l
```

Também existe o parâmetro `--nounistd`, mas creio que este seja especificamente para remover o `unistd.h` do script C que será gerado, no caso creio que `--wincompat` deva ajustar mais coisas interessantes para o Windows.